# How can I avoid a InvalidCastException in .NET?

Tags: c#, casting, .net

Is there a way to check whether a C# cast will be successful? In some cases; based on how a rendered page is put together; inheriting from different Master Pages, some casts will work and others will not.
I am wondering how I can check to see if a cast will be successful or if I just have to catch and handle an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can say :

```
if (Variable is Typename) { 
}
```

Or

```
  Variable = OtherVariable as TypeName;
```

Variable will be null if casting was not possible.

Comment: Heh, I actually knew that -- I'll blame it on Monday. Thanks, I will accept answer as soon as the SO let's me. :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that "as" works only for Reference-Type or Nullable

Comment: Yes because `int?` is equivalent to `Nullable<Int32>` wich is a reference-type

Comment: No, it's a value type, a struct.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use "as" keyword to cast and check if the result is null.